# AWS DMS Source MongoDB and Target RDS Postgres Full load not happening but ongoing replication happens

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, aws-dms, mongodb-replica-set

I created a DMS task:
Source - MongoDB
Target - RDS Postgres

I have **successfully working pipelines with full load + Ongoing replication working.**

But for some **collections** in my source mongo when I create Full load or Full load + Ongoing replication,
**Task shows successfully completed and starts ongoing replication.**
But Full load doesn't happens only schema gets created in postgres with 0 rows, and Ongoing replication starts.
CloudWatch shows no error even after detailed debug.
[image]

Comment: I was able to fix this, actually, the issue was I used the source endpoint with the different schema/collection mentioned. and from the above two collections, one collection name matches another schema table from mongo.

So when I created respective source endpoint for respective schemas it works as expected

Answer (score 0):

In our case it's because of wrong database name configuration in DMS mongoDB endpoint. The table creation and CDC still work, but full load fails.